# Look for a word in a string PHP

Tags: php, string, cpu-word, boolean, preg-match

How to check if specific work available in a string? Let's say I have a string like this

> wrong=name&pass&email

so I want to check if name, pass or/and email are in the string. I need the answer be in boolean so I can do some stuff in there.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: that looks suspiciously like URL fragment ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( stristr( $string, $string_im_looking_for) ){
     echo 'Yep!';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$mystring = 'wrong=name&pass&email';
$findme   = 'name';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);


if ($pos === false) {
echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strstr()`

```
if (strstr($string,'pass'))
{
    echo"pass is here";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the string first. Something like this;

```
$arrayOfWords = explode('&', $yourString);
```

Then you loop through the array and check isset.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your example it seems what you actually want to do is parse a query string, e.g. with [`parse_str`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
parse_str($string, $result);
if(isset($result['name']))
  // Do something
```

However, if the string may be malformed etc. I would suggest using [`strpos`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), as unlike [`strstr`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) and others it doesn't need to create a new string.

```
// Note the `!==` - strpos may return `0`, meaning the word is there at
// the 0th position, however `0 == false` so the `if` statement would fail
// otherwise.
if(strpos($string, 'email') !== false)
  // Do something
```